# how can I count all NA and delete the row

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
    df<-structure(list(best2 = c(8972.7, 1944, 2022.7, 13001.7, NA, 3228.6, 
NA, 186.4, 100, 2655.9), best3 = c(2634.4, 1181.3, 505.2, 2802.4, 
NA, 1707.6, NA, 186.4, 100, 1219), best4 = c(3079.3, 1512.9, 
NA, 2804.5, NA, 1597.6, NA, 186.4, 100, 1558.2), best5 = c(8972.7, 
1944, NA, 13001.7, NA, 3228.6, NA, 186.4, 100, 2655.9), best6 = c(2634.4, 
1181.3, NA, 2802.4, NA, 1707.6, NA, 186.4, 100, 1219), best7 = c(3079.3, 
1512.9, NA, 2804.5, NA, 1597.6, NA, 186.4, 100, 1558.2), best8 = c(8972.7, 
1944, NA, 13001.7, NA, 3228.6, NA, 186.4, 100, 2655.9), best9 = c(2634.4, 
1181.3, NA, 2802.4, NA, 1707.6, NA, 186.4, 100, 1219)), .Names = c("best2", 
"best3", "best4", "best5", "best6", "best7", "best8", "best9"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to do all these stuff at once

1-count number of rows that have all cells empty or NA

answer: 2

2-count rows with constant values for all cells

answer: 2

3-count rows with first half empty cells

answer: 0

4-count rows with second half empty cells

answer: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `apply` function to iterate over the rows of your `data.frame`. Then, we use `rowSums` on the logical vectors.

```
rowSums(all_logicals <- apply(df, 1, function(r){
    n <- length(r)
    nc2 <- n / 2
    nc2_plus1 <- nc2 + 1
    c('allNA' = all(is.na(r)),
    'allconstant' = (length(unique(r)) == 1 & !all(is.na(r))),
    'firsthalf' = all(is.na(r[1:nc2])) & !all(is.na(r[nc2_plus1:n])),
    'secondhalf' = all(is.na(r[nc2_plus1:n])) & !all(is.na(r[1:nc2])))
}))

  allNA allconstant   firsthalf  secondhalf 
      2           2           0           1
```

It may be helpful to see the results from `apply` which are passed to `rowSums`:

```
all_logicals

             [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
allNA       FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
allconstant FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
firsthalf   FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
secondhalf  FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

#### Edit - using the results to remove rows

We can use `all_logicals` to find the row indexes which we wish to remove:

```
remove_rows <- unique(unlist(apply(all_logicals, 1, which)))
(df_sub <- df[-remove_rows,])

     best2  best3  best4   best5  best6  best7   best8  best9
1   8972.7 2634.4 3079.3  8972.7 2634.4 3079.3  8972.7 2634.4
2   1944.0 1181.3 1512.9  1944.0 1181.3 1512.9  1944.0 1181.3
4  13001.7 2802.4 2804.5 13001.7 2802.4 2804.5 13001.7 2802.4
6   3228.6 1707.6 1597.6  3228.6 1707.6 1597.6  3228.6 1707.6
10  2655.9 1219.0 1558.2  2655.9 1219.0 1558.2  2655.9 1219.0
```

Comment: is it possible to also add how to remove each of them ? for example first allNA, then allcontsnt , then those that are first half and then those that are second half?

Comment: @nik i have edited my answer demonstrating one way to do that